# Difference between these 2 swiping tabs implementations?

Tags: android

I have a working code for having 3 tabs, with 3 fragments that you can either horizontally swipe between to change, or you can click on the tab to go to the requested fragment.
However, I wanted to do some tweaks to my design, and I went over to the Android Developer's website: [Creating swipe views with tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral)
, and it looks completely different than mine. Now I wonder if I should use the code in the developer's website, or keep my own.

Right now I am using ViewPager + TabLayout.

So simple, yet working.
This also makes me wonder, how come this simple code works, but in the official documentation there's a long story. It just makes me think that if I keep my code in the current design, I might encounter some big problems in the future. 
Or - if it works - then it works?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        TabsAdapter adapter = new TabsAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Find the tab layout that shows the tabs
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        // Connect the tab layout with the view pager. This will
        //   1. Update the tab layout when the view pager is swiped
        //   2. Update the view pager when a tab is selected
        //   3. Set the tab layout's tab names with the view pager's adapter's titles
        //      by calling onPageTitle()
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

TabsAdapter.java:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    /** Context of the app */
    private Context mContext;


    public TabsAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Return the {@link Fragment} that should be displayed for the given page number.
     */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new NbFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new LksFragment();
        } else {
            return new ChtFragment();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the total number of pages.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return mContext.getString(R.string.category_nb);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return mContext.getString(R.string.category_lks);
        } else {
            return mContext.getString(R.string.category_cht);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.barebones.barebones.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/CategoryTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you can see it is completely different than the one on their website. How could it be? I would love to get some clarification, because as a beginner, I feel lost in this sea of information. Which method should I use in order to have swiping tabs that represent different fragments?

Answer (score 1):

I'm lost what you're trying to solve here. Are you perhaps trying to make it so that when you swipe horizontally, respectively changing fragments, your tab layout is updated as well? If so. I have a snippet down below, which you may have to adjust based on your variable names.

```
protected void initializeNavigationTransition() {
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            tabs_bottom_nav.getTabAt(i).select();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

    tabs_bottom_nav.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            updateTabIconOnSelect(current_tab, tab.getPosition());
            current_tab = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

I'll have an additional note that it is possible for fragments to refresh, meaning it will be reinitialized, which might be something you do not want, especially if you're displaying data unto these fragments, which you are fetching from your API or over the network, after swiping a couple of times to different fragments if you have probably at least 4 fragments within the view pager. Hence you would need to prevent the view pager from refreshing the fragments by using the code below

```
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); // 4 is the number of fragments within your view pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
```

I believe the cause of fragments refreshing is caused by the viewpager trying to save memory

Comment: I simply want to have 3 tabs, with 3 fragments, that I can horizontally swipe between, each fragment has its own data (For example fragment 1 holds profile page, fragment 2 holds list of favorite animals, fragment 3 is for settings). Now my simple code already shows these 3 fragments and I can simply add the data I wish. But why is the code in their official documentation so different to accomplish this task?

Comment: I see. What you're seeing on the documentation are different methods of how you want to show the user which fragment they are in. In this case, the method you used is by using the tab layout. Others, shown in the documentation are by using title strips, or another tab layout which is located just below the action bar. Just google them and you should see the difference of what they each look like.

Comment: thank you, so for my purposed (having 3 fragments to display 3 different "static" pages) -it's a good implementation of swiping tabs?

Comment: Yes your implementation should be good enough as long as it works. If in case you encounter that the fragments you are using within the viewpager are refreshing or being reinitialized, then consider using the code I noted below this answer. So far, that's the only issue I've encountered doing the same implementation as you are using right now. If this has been helpful to you, consider marking this as answered by checking my answer.